# JPA Entitities vs EntityManager with simple db query

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I'm relatively new to Java but have quite a bit of experience with databases.  I've been reading the past week on various ways to access databases in JAVA for a web service and I've gone through a couple of Netbeans tutorials for this.

I need to create a simple web service that queries and retrieves fairly minimal data from the database.  I need to lookup a single value based on a unique key and return it, and do a single record insert into a child table.  I'm trying to decide whether to do this via a few simple queries or to use JPA entities.

In other languages, I would have just written the code to make the DB connection and massage the data myself, but I see that Java has the ability to use Entities to represent the different tables and do all of the "heavy lifting" using JPA.  However, this seems like a whole lot of overhead for a few simple queries for a web service.  I'm curious if someone could tell me what the overhead is for using the JPA and entities versus just using EntityManager with a simple SQL statement to pull my data?  Are there any benefits that you have found to using one versus the other?  When I've seen development platforms build the extra objects in the past, there has usually been added layers of complexity and performance hits.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think overhead is not really a big deal using JPA vs use EntityManager with SQL queries.

In fact you will add more overhead trying to use EntityManager just to execute SQL queries. In the domain of JPA those queries are named "Native Queries".

One instant benefit of using JPA vs Query approach is the ORM this allow you to avoid create any kind of query and pass named parameters in a big insert statement and create the objects from the resultSet automatically, you wont be worried anymore to loop the ResultSet and extract the columns to create your beans.

Actually if you want to execute queries you need to create the same Java Beans to manage the returned objects, so add some annotations it wont be a big deal.

For the kind of project that you want to create, it will be easier just expend a little more time configuring your app but when you call `em.persist(entity)` instead of having `INSERT INTO table values (?,?,?,?,?)`, you will love it, and other persistent operations.

Think in JPA as a solution to make the Object Relational Mapping easier, non-intrusive persistence layer, POJO based.

At the end, the model of JPA is simple and elegant, powerful and flexible, could be paintfull when you want to configure your database model but it is not your case.

Comment: Koitoer.  Thank you for your input.  I really appreciate it.  I will continue on down the path of JPA and see what happens.  Thank you again.